# Subtracting timestamps with different timezone oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, epoch

I am trying to subtract two timestamp columns from each other. One of them is in Asia/Jerusalem and the other one is in utc. I was wondering in which time zone am I gonna get the results.
I am doing so to try and get epoch seconds from my timestamp column(timestamp stored in Asia/Jerusalem)
The table is stored in oracle db

I created a timestamp column with the value '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000' at utc timezone and subtructed the two columns resulting in epoch time that is two hours later than expected

Comment: Are the columns `timestamp with time zone` or just plain `timestamp`? If the latter how can you tell which time zone the values are supposed to in - do you just know one is always UTC and the other is always Jerusalem (and how do you handle DST)? You would need to know, and convert them, before subtracting. It would help if you gave a [mre] with tables, data, and current and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting one timestamp from another returns an interval, and intervals do not have a time zone.

For example, if you run the following:

```
WITH cteData
  AS (SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
             TIMESTAMP '2023-10-05 08:00:00 -02:00' AS TEST_TIMESTAMP
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       TEST_TIMESTAMP,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - TEST_TIMESTAMP AS RESULTING_INTERVAL
  FROM cteData;
```

you'll get results similar to:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   05-OCT-23 08.57.59.127452 AM -04:00  
TEST_TIMESTAMP      05-OCT-23 08.00.00.000000000 AM -02:00
RESULTING_INTERVAL  +000000000 02:57:59.127452000
```